# Generating a random date before January 1, 1900

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

So I am trying to make a random date generator that can accept years from 0 to 9999.  The problem is that entering a year before January 1, 1900 will not be able to read it.  Is there a way that I can make a random date generate before January 1, 1900?  Thank you

Comment: Also, I want a random month in text format like Jan, Feb, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use automatic coercion of text strings to dates, instead of the `date()` function, like this:

`=to_date( join("-", randbetween(100, 9999 + 100), randbetween(1, 12), randbetween(1, 28)) + randbetween(0, 3) - 100 * 365 )`

The `100` bit is required to avoid the undesirable detection of years like `91` as  `1991`.

To format the date as "17 *Sep* 2021", use **Format > Number > More formats > More date and time formats**.

See [this answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/153710/269219) for an explanation of how date and time values work in spreadsheets.

Answer (score 0):

Using negative numbers can also turn the numbers into dates `=RANDBETWEEN(-1,DATE(1999, 12, 31))` Just figured this out